# In Django ,how to access the data of dictionary inside lists of a dictionary from views.py in index.html(template)

Tags: django

I load my data in my view:

```
eanList = [12345678, 123400348]
dict_pass = {
    'eanList': [12345678,123400348],
    '12345678': [
        {'Ean_code': 12345678, 'Img_url': http://img.jpg, 'Product_title': mobilephone},
        {'market': amazon, 'price': 5000},
        {'market': flipkart, 'price': 5700},
    ],
    '123400348': [
        {'Ean_code': 123400348, 'Img_url': http://img2.jpg, 'Product_title': mobilephone2},
        {'market': amazon, 'price': 7000},
        {'market': flipkart, 'price': 8700},
    ],
}
return render(request,'first_app/index.html',{'dict_pass': dict_pass, 'eanlist': eanList})
```

Now, I want to display my data in the template:

**index.html**

```
{% for ean in eanlist %}
{{ dict_pass.ean.1.Product_Title}}
{{ dict_pass.ean.1.Img_url}}
```

How can I access that data? My code in the template is not working.

Comment: Is it possible to format you dictionary a little prettier :) I can take a look then.

Comment: I’m your eanList are they stored as strings?

Comment: Where is the eanList dict? Here you have showed us only `dict_pass` and in your render function you are also returning `eanList`